# how to set up a cronjob to run on the last sunday of each month?

Tags: linux, unix, centos7, redhat, system-administration

I am trying to set up a cronjob to run on the last sunday of each month. This is what I have accomplished.

Right now, it is running every sunday at 10 PM.

0 22 * * 0 /usr/basys_bin/clean_cups_cache.sh

Comment: @larsk last day is not the same as last Sunday.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/550835/cron-entry-for-last-saturday